# How to write conditions in self join that changes with current iteration of a row

Tags: mysql, sql

A table (test) has a description

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| task  | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| time  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| type  | char(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and contains data

```
+------+------+------+
| task | time | type |
+------+------+------+
| T1   |    1 | S    |
| T2   |    2 | S    |
| T1   |    7 | E    |
| T1   |    8 | S    |
| T1   |   14 | E    |
| T2   |   15 | E    |
| T1   |   16 | S    |
| T2   |   17 | S    |
| T3   |   20 | S    |
| T1   |   21 | E    |
| T3   |   25 | E    |
+------+------+------+
```

represents data set for a task started(S) or completed(E) at some time unit. Is it possible to join it in a way which outputs a table with task start time and end time. here (T2, 17, S) is skipped in final output as there is no data on end time for it yet.

Final result:-

```
+------+------+------+
| task | start| end  |
+------+------+------+
| T1   |    1 | 7    |
| T2   |    2 | 15   |
| T1   |    8 | 14   |
| T1   |   16 | 21   |
| T3   |   20 | 25   |
+------+------+------+
```

As can be seen in the final result, all time frames for a task T (T1) is mutually exclusive [(1,7),(8,15),(16,25)].

Can't figure out condition rules for join

```
select S_table.task, S_table.time as start, E_table.time as end
from (select * from test where type='S') as S_table
left join (select * from test where type='E') as E_table
on
S_table.task = E_table.task
and
E_table.time should be greater than previous E_table.time for same task
and
E_table.time should be least within S_table.time < E_table.time
```

- In result table for first row all E_table.time (7,15,14,21,25) is greater than S_table.time (current row being looked at i.e. 1) but 7 is the least one hence picked
- In result table for second row all E_table.time greater than previous (7) i.e. (15,14,21,25) is greater than 2 but least one i.e. 15 is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each start time you need to get the min time of type 'E' that is greater than that start time:

```
select t.* from (
  select 
    t.task,
    t.time start,
    (select min(time) from test where type = 'E' and task = t.task and time > t.time) end
  from test t 
  where t.type = 'S' 
) t
where t.end is not null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ikbJupjFcERQ4my4vXg4Q/0).
Results:

```
| task | start | end |
| ---- | ----- | --- |
| T1   | 1     | 7   |
| T2   | 2     | 15  |
| T1   | 8     | 14  |
| T1   | 16    | 21  |
| T3   | 20    | 25  |
```

You can get the same results with an **inner** self join like your code:

```
select S_table.task, S_table.time as start, E_table.time as end
from (select * from test where type='S') as S_table
inner join (select * from test where type='E') as E_table
on
S_table.task = E_table.task
and 
E_table.time = (
  select min(time) from test where type = 'E' and task = S_table.task and time > S_table.time
)
order by S_table.time
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i was looking for.